# Show Pivot Column only when it has a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am battling... AGAIN!

I have the following query (Thanx to [This](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/))

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotSelectColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName 
        = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
        + QUOTENAME(Wcode)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT WCode FROM DataInputTotal) AS WC

----Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column with isnull
SELECT @PivotSelectColumnNames 
    = ISNULL(@PivotSelectColumnNames + ',','')
    + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(WCode) + ', 0) AS '
    + QUOTENAME(WCode)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT WCode FROM DataInputTotal) AS WC


--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT Top 10  FleetNo, LogNo, ProdDate, ShiftType, ' + @PivotSelectColumnNames + '
    FROM DataInputTotal
    PIVOT(SUM(Hrs) 
          FOR WCode IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable
          WHERE PRODDATE BETWEEN ''20170328'' AND ''20170329'' AND SITENAME = ''MUMI'' 
                  ORDER By DataInputID DESC'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

All Runs pretty well. All I would really like is to Drop the Columns with no value. Is there a way?

```
FleetNo LogNo           Date                    Shift   101     102     103     104     105
K601    N3292017601P    2017-03-29 00:00:00.000 Night   12.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
K601    D3292017601P    2017-03-29 00:00:00.000 Day     12.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
K601    N3282017601P.   2017-03-28 00:00:00.000 Night   12.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
K601    N3282017601P    2017-03-28 00:00:00.000 Day     12.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
K536    N3292017536P    2017-03-29 00:00:00.000 Night   12.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
TLB008  N3292017TLB008P 2017-03-29 00:00:00.000 Night   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
TLB004  N3292017TLB004P 2017-03-29 00:00:00.000 Night   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
TLB003  N3292017TLB003P 2017-03-29 00:00:00.000 Night   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
TLB002  N3292017TLB002P 2017-03-29 00:00:00.000 Night   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
K910    N3292017910P    2017-03-29 00:00:00.000 Night   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

I should also point out this will be represented in a DateGridView on a userform.

Altered Script:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotSelectColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB..#TEMP')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Temp
END

SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM DataInputTotal 
WHERE PRODDATE BETWEEN '20170328' AND '20170329' AND SITENAME = 'MUMI'

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 

SELECT @ColumnName 
        = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
        + QUOTENAME(Wcode)
FROM (SELECT WCode 
     FROM #TEMP
     GROUP BY WCode HAVING SUM(Hrs) > 0) AS WC

----Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column with isnull
SELECT @PivotSelectColumnNames 
    = ISNULL(@PivotSelectColumnNames + ',','')
    + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(WCode) + ', 0) AS '
    + QUOTENAME(WCode)
FROM (SELECT WCode 
     FROM #TEMP 
     GROUP BY WCode HAVING SUM(Hrs) > 0) AS WC


--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT Top 10  FleetNo, LogNo, ProdDate, ShiftType, SiteName, ' + @PivotSelectColumnNames + '
    FROM #TEMP
    PIVOT(SUM(Hrs) 
          FOR WCode IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

        --Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to restrict @ColumnName generation.

```
--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName 
        = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
        + QUOTENAME(Wcode)
FROM 
(
     SELECT WCode 
     FROM DataInputTotal 
     WHERE PRODDATE BETWEEN '20170328' AND '20170329' AND SITENAME = 'MUMI'
     GROUP BY WCode HAVING SUM(Hrs) > 0
) AS WC
```

I suggest to create a table variable or temp table storing filtered data to avoid duplication. Like this:

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM DataInputTotal 
WHERE PRODDATE BETWEEN '20170328' AND '20170329' AND SITENAME = 'MUMI'
```

at the beginning and replace DataInputTotal in following statements.

Comment: thank you for your quick response, but unfortunately it still returns all columns irrespective of the value.

Comment: Can you try to print @ColumnName and @ PivotSelectColumnNames for troubleshooting?

Comment: @ColumnName: [119],[115],[120],[114],[304],[204],[113],[209],[117],[108],[217],[306],[213],[301],[207],[212],[211],[219],[107],[216],[105],[112],[208],[221],[121],[122],[206],[220],[102],[106],[214],[218],[215],[109],[201],[110],[104],[118],[101],[111],[202],[103],[203],[210],[305],[303],[205]

Comment: @PivotSelectColumnNames: ISNULL([119], 0) AS [119],ISNULL([115], 0) AS [115],ISNULL([120], 0) AS [120],ISNULL([114], 0) AS [114],ISNULL([304], 0) AS [304],ISNULL([204], 0) AS [204],ISNULL([113], 0) AS [113],ISNULL([209], 0) AS [209],ISNULL([117], 0) AS [117],ISNULL([108], 0) AS [108],ISNULL([217], 0) AS [217],ISNULL([306], 0) AS [306],ISNULL([213], 0) AS [213],ISNULL([301], 0) AS [301],ISNULL([207], 0) AS [207],ISNULL([212], 0) AS [212],ISNULL([211], 0) AS [211],ISNULL([219], 0) AS [219],ISNULL([107], 0) AS [107],ISNULL([216], 0) AS

Comment: I removed some items to allow for character length

Comment: I see. You need to copy WHERE clause in final PIVOT statement to above query as well.

Comment: Sorry, that is very cryptic, can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Check my updated answer. Note, you need to the same for @ PivotSelectColumnNames, but I won't repeat it here.

Comment: Wow... not my brightest moment, I have made the changes as suggested, but it still shows all the columns, I have added the altered script above